# Checking Android app for OpenSSL vulnerability

Tags: android, openssl

I used the terminal command unzip -p app.apk | strings | grep "OpenSSL" as suggested [here](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/6376725)

I get the following result in terminal:

```
GmsCore_OpenSSL
+com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl
7org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl
OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
%s(%d): OpenSSL internal error, assertion failed: %s
OpenSSL DH Method
OpenSSL X9.42 DH method
OpenSSL PKCS#3 DH method
OpenSSL CMAC method
OpenSSL HMAC method
OpenSSL EC algorithm
OpenSSL RSA method
OpenSSL DSA method
OpenSSL ECDSA method
OpenSSL ECDH method
You need to read the OpenSSL FAQ, http://www.openssl.org/support/faq.html
OpenSSL default
OpenSSL default user interface
OpenSSL 'dlfcn' shared library method
TLSv1 part of OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
SSLv3 part of OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
DTLSv1 part of OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
MD5 part of OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
SHA1 part of OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
SHA-256 part of OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
SHA-512 part of OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
Big Number part of OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
EC part of OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
(1RSA part of OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
Diffie-Hellman part of OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
Stack part of OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
lhash part of OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
EVP part of OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
ASN.1 part of OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
PEM part of OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
X.509 part of OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
DES part of OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
libdes part of OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
AES part of OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
RC2 part of OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
IDEA part of OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
CAMELLIA part of OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
EDSA part of OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
ECDSA part of OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
ECDH part of OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
RAND part of OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
CONF part of OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
CONF_def part of OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
TXT_DB part of OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
RC4 part of OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
SHA-256 part of OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015
cU!
   }AES part of OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015
```

- Does anyone know how to interpret these?!
- The last line causes concern "OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015". Should I worry about this? If so how do I find out where the issue is and how to fix it?!

Thank You.